# Getting error when scaffolding with laravel ui + vue js in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

[image: npm install && npm run dev]

composer required laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install && npm run dev

What I left?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
npm install webpack --save
```

Check this link too, might help: https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/623

Comment: Still same error

Comment: He's using Vite, not Laravel Mix/Webpack.